# Wrong result from query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this simple query

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `book` 
WHERE  `BookID` =  '7u'
LIMIT 1
```

i expect empty result
But i see one result with book id =7. 
BookID is auto increment.
Why query ignore 'u' character?

Comment: There are no "characters" in numbers, and BookID is a numeric field.

Comment: When you say this is the wrong result, what were you expecting? Did you want an empty result? (Presumably '7u' is not permitted in your `BookID` field).

Comment: you are right halfer.  i edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `7u` is not numeric, so apparently mysql is ignoring the `u`.

Maybe you are thinking of some high level programming languages which use suffixes to qualify the type of number?  In C-derived languages, 7u would be an unsigned integer with value 7.

Comment: In other words, when you compare a numeric field against a non-numeric value, it probably converts it to an integer/number

Comment: can i do something to prevent this or any solution?

Comment: @user1903750:  Remove the `u`.  Why is it there in the first place?  Also, look at the data.  With an autoincrement column, it is strictly numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Just because of two reasons:

1. There may be only one record.
2. you were using LIMIT 1. That display only one record from the output. so use LIMIT 5 OR 2.

Comment: hi. u missed my point. my question is i expect no result but i get one. check wallyk answer.

Answer (score 0):

the mysql takes the string as 7u so when you try to do this stuff it coverts in a string but mysql is not in strict mode so it coverts string into integer because your id is intenger and its rounding of 7u becomes 7 thats why its display the one record try without quote 7u instead of '7u' then it gives error